# Recursively unpacking a list in a Django template

Tags: django

I have the following list which I'd like to unpack in my template (this is stored in `eachpart.1`)

```
[u'Value1', u'Value2', Value3, Value4, [u'Value1', u'Value2', Value3, Value4], [u'Value1', u'Value2', Value3, Value4]]
```

Most of the time the format is like this:

```
[u'Value1', u'Value2', Value3, Value4]
```

This is displayed in my template as follows:

```
<tr>
    <td width = 150px><a href="#">{{eachpart.0}}</a></td>
    <td>{{eachpart.1.0}}</td>
    <td><img src = "eachpart.1.1}}.jpg" alt="{{eachpart.1.1}}">
    </td>
</tr>
```

But every once in a while I get the corner case at the top, which can be of unknown repetitions.

I detect this in my template as follows:

```
 {% if eachpart.1|length > 4 %}
```

This tells me that I have one of these corner cases. So now I want to basically determine the number of entries (which will be `eachpart.1|length - 1`) and for each of these entries I want to use a counter to access the correct value.

Is this possible in a template? Is it possible to do a while loop and counter in a template?

Or am I going about this in a totally inefficient way?

Comment: I guess you could make it easier with a custom template tag

Comment: Ok... I'd rather do it in the template because I'm a bit lazy to brush up on template tags :-) But I'll do that if that's the only way.

Comment: Since doing it in Python is way easier, maybe you should transform your list before passing it to template

Comment: You can use `type` function to check if it's of `str` type or `list` type. But it will be best to use template tags.